# List comprehension troubles

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to have a string if a certain condition is true but if the condition is not true then put the empty string in (or empty list).

for example : `[  Bob  | i <- [3..6], i == 4  ]` this gives the list `["Bob"]` but I want to get: `[ "" , "Bob" , "" , "" ]` so any empty string whenever `i` does not equal 4.

Is it possible to do this within a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `if` construction.

```
[ if i == 4 then "Bob" else "" | i <- [3..6] ]
```

Though this is probably better without a list comprehension

```
map f [3..6]
  where
  f 4 = "Bob"
  f _ = ""
```

Comment: I so wish I had seen this `map` expression before I composed my sorry solution. It is a gem and yet another reason to love Haskell. I eschew `if-then-else` and wish it were a function.  Haskell is so versatile with syntax `let { f 4 = "Bob"; f _ = "" } in map (\s -> f s) [3..6]
` I learn new everyday here from super people like you. Thank you so much.

Comment: @fpmora N.B. that `\s -> f s` is just `(($) f)` which is just `f` :)

Comment: Wow! I am so impressed. I always forget about applying partial functions. Thank you so very much for this: `let { f 4 = "Bob"; f _ = "" } in map f [3..6]` I love, love, love one liners and people with terrific insight.

Comment: @fpmora Willem's bottom answer is the best here, imo. `map (bool "" "Bob" . (==4)) [3..6]`

Comment: I don't understand how or what `bool` does. I'm still having trouble with basic prelude and a little Data.List. I've had books on lisp for over 20 years and on Hope & Haskell for almost as long but only recently am I able to use Haskell at work and so happy I am.

Comment: `bool` expects two values, a partial function to use as predicate, and a value to test. `bool ifFalse ifTrue p x` is the same as `if p x then ifTrue else ifFalse`.

Comment: Do I feel dumb. I am trying everything to avoid `if-then-else` and it's been right here and there all of the time. Google has been little help. Thank you again so very much. `bool' is just beautiful. I looked up book on Zevon, my go to but it looked daunting. Your explanation is superbub,  very.

Answer (score 3):

Left side of the pipe does not have to be a value. You can do it like this: `[ if i == 4 then "Bob" else "" | i <- [3..6]]`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this does not work is because you use `i == 4` as a *filter*:

```
[ "Bob" | i <- [3..6], i == 4  ]
--                     ^ filter
```

So that means that only in case `i == 4`, you will add `"Bob"` to the list. In case the condition was `True` for instance two times (for example `i < 5`), then we would yield `"Bob"` twice.

The condition is not a filter: it determines *what* should be added to the list, not *on what condition* something should be added. In that case you can use function that checks the condition, and returns different results.

We can use [**`bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool) for this (this is a *catamoprhism* over `Bool`):

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

[ bool "" "Bob" (i == 4) | i <- [3..6] ]
```

Note that we can use `map` as well:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

map (bool "" "Bob" . (4 ==)) [3..6]
```

Comment: I love `bool` after it was explained to me here. I so very wanted an `if` function like in other functional languages. `bool` now serves the purpose. Thank you so very much for this.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with what you have. It's just you have to force the result whether it meets the condition or doesn't. The way to do that is to put what you have in a list comprehension and have it "execute" a number of times.

```
[ concat ["Bob" | x == 4] | x <- [3..6] ]
```

The condition of x not equal 4 produces and empty list '[]' so `concat` converts them to identical strings for list uniformity.

Comment: This will return `[[], ["Bob"], [], []]` instead of `["", "Bob", "", ""]`. It adds another layer of lists than it should.

Comment: That's what I said because the question was: ”I want to use a list comprehension to have a string if a certain condition is true but if the condition is not true then put the **empty string in (or empty list).**"

Comment: [] and ”" prove to be identical. [] == "" -> True

Comment: @fpmora but `[String]` and `[[String]]` are not identical (`["Bob"] /= "Bob"`)

Comment: That's right and `[[a]] /= [a]` but `[""] == [[]]` results `True`.

Comment: Just  `[ concat [ "Bob" | x == 4]   | x <- [3..6] ]` to satisfy appearance.

Comment: I don't really know what this `[[], ["Bob"], [], []]` is because Haskell doesn't allow lists of different types within a list. That's why concat works so well as always.

Comment: @4castle: the empty string is an empty list `[] == ""`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know that, but in my comment the `[]` is of type `[String]`, so it would be wrong to write it as `""`, which is of type `String`.